# Can the "in"s be omitted in "one danger to be aware of in using meaning in this way"?

Tags: prepositions

> one danger to be aware of **in** using meaning **in** this way to decide countability is the existence of exceptions

Can I omit both bolded "in"s? It seems unfamiliar to me that some preposition directly follows the other. I've been seeing "this way" used by itself not with "in". So I think:

> one danger to be aware of using meaning this way to decide countability is the existence of exceptions

Even though these 2 versions have slightly different meaning this version is also grammatically correct. Is that right?

Comment: The first **in** means 'when you are' using. You _could_ omit both, but the sentence reads much better as it stands.

Comment: @KateBunting thanks!!